# How to insert multiple dropdown value in database?

Tags: codeigniter

I have many dropdown list in my html and I want to send each value from some dropdown in database (which dropdown I open and select any value that should go into database with the dropdown name as well).

Database will show like this that this user selected value 1 from "ABC Dropdown" and value 3 from "XYZ" dropdown and etc etc and those dropdown whose value I don't select should not go into database.

```
 <pre>
    <tr class="evenrow">
        <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="report_id[]" id="report_id" value="1">1</td>
        <td>Customer Balances</td>
        <td>
            <select  name="printer[]" id="printer" class="form-control" title="">
                <option value="">Browser support</option>
                <option value="1">QL500&nbsp;-&nbsp;Label printer</option>
                <option value="2">Samsung&nbsp;-&nbsp;Main network printer</option>
                <option value="3">Local&nbsp;-&nbsp;Local print server at user IP</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="evenrow">
        <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="report_id[]" id="report_id" value="2">2</td>
        <td>Customer Balances</td>
        <td>
            <select  name="printer[]" id="printer" class="form-control" title="">
                <option value="">Browser support</option>
                <option value="1">QL500&nbsp;-&nbsp;Label printer</option>
                <option value="2">Samsung&nbsp;-&nbsp;Main network printer</option>
                <option value="3">Local&nbsp;-&nbsp;Local print server at user IP</option>
            </select>

        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="evenrow">
        <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="report_id[]" id="report_id" value="3">3</td>
        <td>Customer Balances</td>
        <td>
            <select  name="printer[]" id="printer" class="form-control" title="">
                <option value="">Browser support</option>
                <option value="1">QL500&nbsp;-&nbsp;Label printer</option>
                <option value="2">Samsung&nbsp;-&nbsp;Main network printer</option>
                <option value="3">Local&nbsp;-&nbsp;Local print server at user IP</option>
            </select>

        </td>
    </tr>

        <tr class="evenrow">
        <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="report_id[]" id="report_id" value="4">4</td>
        <td>Customer Balances</td>
        <td>
            <select  name="printer[]" id="printer" class="form-control" title="">
                <option value="">Browser support</option>
                <option value="1">QL500&nbsp;-&nbsp;Label printer</option>
                <option value="2">Samsung&nbsp;-&nbsp;Main network printer</option>
                <option value="3">Local&nbsp;-&nbsp;Local print server at user IP</option>
            </select>

        </td>
    </tr>


    </table>



    </div>

    <!-- /.box-body -->
    </div>
       <center>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Add New" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
            </div>
    </center>
    </pre>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using the different name instead of same at all.

```
Report1, Printer1
Report2, Printer2
Report3, Printer3
```

and in controller you can catch them by the name...

```
<table>
   <tr class="evenrow">
        <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="report_id1" id="report_id" value="1">1</td>
        <td>Customer Balances</td>
        <td>
            <select  name="printer1" id="printer" class="form-control" title="">
                <option value="">Browser Support</option>
                <option value="1">Text</option>
                <option value="2">Text</option>
                <option value="3">Text</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="evenrow">
        <td align="center"><input type="hidden" name="report_id2" id="report_id" value="2">2</td>
        <td>Customer Balances</td>
        <td>
            <select  name="printer2" id="printer" class="form-control" title="">
                <option value="">Browser Support</option>
                <option value="1">Text</option>
                <option value="2">Text</option>
                <option value="3">Text</option>
            </select>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

And then in controller :

```
$report1 = $this->input->post('report1');
$report2 = $this->input->post('report2');
$printer1= $this->input->post('printer1');
$printer2= $this->input->post('printer2');
```

Answer (score 0):

you used array for select box name and all three select box have same name so if you want to store all different section values differ change select box name so you get the 2 different array in controller or you can easily identifier from which section its got and make a customer json

`$selected_option= array("section1"=>$this->input->post('printer1',"section2"=>$this->input->post('printer2');
$selected_option_json= json_encode($selected_option);`

store $selected_option_json(its a json string) in db

Hope its helpful for you.